Open search latency impacts redis latency
I have been load testing my kotlin application. The application queries Open search and redis. What is happening is when the Open search is serving requests with a low latency, the logged latency for redis is also low. But when the open search latency is high the redis latency logged is also high.Not sure why it might be happening. Open search call happens first and then redis call happens.Not able to figure out the issue.
Using dogstatsd for logging the metrics.
Few details:
Open search config -> 3 master + 4 data nodes
Redis config -> 1 primary + 5 replicas
Everything is on AWS and in the same region.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
